# Why nodemon fail when using -- exec babel-node?

Tags: node.js, babeljs, nodemon

I have installed the bable-cli and the babel-preset-env, after installing nodemon the npm start fail to load my application when using the following in the package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/index.js --exec babel-node"
  }
```

**Showing the following error:**

```
[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `babel-node src/index.js`
'"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**But everything works fine when using the following:**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node src/index.js"
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and solved it this way:
"scripts": {
"start": "babel-node src/index.js"
"dev"  : "nodemon --exec npm start"
}

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30593301)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because you are not sending anything to ***babel*** to transpire and run. ***nodemon*** just looks for file changes.

Try this instead.

```
"serve":nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js
```

If that doesn't work make sure you have the proper DEV dependencies.

```
@babel/core
@babel/node
@babel/cli
@babel/preset-env
```

configure .babelrc to have the following

```
{ 
  "presets" : ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Comment: Hello Dallas, I already have the .babelrc setup. and unfortunately, the "serve" is not working.

Comment: make sure you have *@babel/cli* install as well. 


 `"start": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js "` in your package.json file and then run `npm run start` in your terminal.

Comment: The following works fine because I have @babel/cli install:  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node src/index.js"
  } 

Because I use import/export instead of require

Comment: Right but it needs to be `nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js`